# Glossary and Bibliography in the appendix chapter/section numbering

Tags: glossaries, appendices

Using the `appendices`, `tocbibind` and `glossaries` package I was able to add the heading of the appendices to the toc and assign them a certain document structure level. How do I make these headings appear like regular section headings. (With numbering and all)

foo.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[toc,nogroupskip,nopostdot,section]{glossaries}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,section]{tocbibind}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{ec}{EC}{Elliptic Curve}
\newacronym{ftp}{FTP}{File Transfer Protocol}
\newacronym{hkdf}{HKDF}{HMAC-based Extract-and-Expand Key Derivation Function}
\newacronym{http}{HTTP}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}
\newacronym{https}{HTTPS}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure}
\newacronym{iot}{IoT}{Internet of things}
\newacronym{nfc}{NFC}{Near-field communication}
\newacronym{pki}{PKI}{Public Key Infrastructure}
\newacronym{smtp}{SMTP}{Simple Mail Transfer Protocol}
\newacronym{tcp}{TCP}{Transmission Control Protocol}
\newacronym{tls}{TLS}{Transport Layer Security}

\newglossaryentry{pfs}
{
    name={perfect forward secrecy},
    description={
        Perfect forward secrecy means that an attacker is required to compromise
        both of the private keys used to establish the session key, to be able
        to decrypt the traffic encrypted with said session key.
    }
}


\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}

\title{foobar}
\author{Philippe}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\gls{ec} \gls{ftp} \gls{hkdf} 

\chapter{Second}
\gls{http} \gls{https} \gls{iot} 

\chapter{Third}
\gls{nfc} \gls{pki} \gls{smtp} 

\chapter{Fourth}
\gls{tcp} \gls{tls} \gls{pfs}\cite{post}


\begin{appendices}
    \printglossaries

    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{foo}

    \section{More appendices}
    Find the Proof of concept source code on the USB-Stick
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

foo.bib:

```
@misc{post,
    title  = {{Glossary and Bibliography in the appendix chapter/section numbering}},
    author = {{Philippe}},
    url    = {{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493644/glossary-and-bibliography-in-the-appendix-chapter-section-numbering}},
}
```

I want the Bibliography, glossary, and More Appendices to appear as sections numbered with letters in the Appendix

Comment: Please provide an MWE (compilable code from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you have tried

Comment: @PeterWilson I added an example.